# proper usages of url encoding

Tags: http, http-headers

I am making an HTTP Client where I need to send HTTP get request to fetch data. I am using boost asio library, hence I have no way to use any standard url encoding library.

Here is what I got from netcat and Mozilla(a typical get request)

```
localhost:2000/questions/10838702/how-to-encode or-d   ecode-url-in-objective-c
```

Get Request Url

```
F:\pydev>nc -l -p 2000
GET /questions/10838702/how-to-encode%20or-d%20%20%20ecode-url-in-objective-c HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:2000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
```

I found Mozilla only encodes the query part of the url.

I tried this url encoding webpage
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

And it encodes the following url

```
localhost:2000/questions/10838702/how-to-encode or-d   ecode-url-in-objective-c
```

to

```
localhost%3A2000%2Fquestions%2F10838702%2Fhow-to-encode%20or-d%20%20%20ecode-url-in-objective-c
```

Can anyone suggest me where to use URL encoding ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general rule, any character other than alphanumerics (A-Z0-9), <kbd>-</kbd> <kbd>_</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>~</kbd> either have some special purpose in a URL, or are not allowed.

Reserved characters are <kbd>;</kbd> <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>?</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>@</kbd><kbd>&</kbd> <kbd>=</kbd> and <kbd>space</kbd>.  If you use any of those characters in a way other than their special meaning, then you must URL-encode it.  To be safe, a lot of encoders just encode everything that isn't explicitly safe.

For example, let's say you have a file name with a question mark in it (let's name the file `file?name`, and you need to create a URL.  The problem is that `http://somehost.com/file?name` will not be interpreted the way you want it to be.  The url will match `/file` in your web space, and have a search term of `name`.  You have to encode the file name to get the URL `http://somehost.com/file%3Fname`.

The spec allows you to URL-encode any character, even alphanumerics, with the expectation that they will be un-encoded by the server.  You just have to make sure that wherever reserved characters are used for their intended purpose, they are not encoded.  eg: You don't want to encode the colon or slashes in `http://somehost.com` because they are being used as delimters.

The most frequent use of url-encoding is to prepare form data.  In this case you usually start with a set of key-value pairs.  You would construct the encoded data for a form like so (in pseudocode):

1. Encode the key and value
2. Concatenate the key and value with '=' between them to get terms.  eg: `encodedKey=encodedValue`.
3. Repeat 1 and 2 until you have a list of terms
4. Join all the terms with ampersands.  eg: `encKey1=encVal1&encKey2=encVal2`

Decoding is the reverse process:

1. Split the form data along the '&' signs to get an array of terms
2. Split each term on the '=' character to get the encoded key and value
3. Decode the key and value

It sounds simple, but you might be *shocked* at how many people get it wrong.

I have glossed over some of the finer details here.  As always, the relevant specification is the last word.  In this case, [RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt).